# MySql query creates all tables but one with error 1146

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have a mySql query to write for a class but I am getting error 1146, Customer table does not exist, for my Customer table. I fixed all other issues but cannot see where the issue is with the Customer table. Here is my code:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;

USE PiqueExpenses;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JobPay (
    pay_rate DOUBLE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    j_id INT NULL,
    pay_hrs_worked DOUBLE NULL,
    job_mileage DOUBLE NULL,    
    pay_per_mile DOUBLE NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (pay_rate),
  INDEX fk_JobPay_Jobs_idx (j_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_JobPay_Jobs
    FOREIGN KEY (j_id)
    REFERENCES Jobs (job_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


USE PiqueExpenses;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Jobs (
    job_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    em_id INT NULL,
    cus_id INT NULL,
    job_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    job_type VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (job_id),
  INDEX fk_Jobs_Employee_idx (em_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Jobs_Employee
    FOREIGN KEY (em_id)
    REFERENCES Employee (emp_id),
  INDEX fk_Jobs_Customer_idx (cus_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Jobs_Customer
    FOREIGN KEY (cus_id)
    REFERENCES Customer (cust_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


USE PiqueExpenses;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee (
    emp_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    emp_lname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    emp_initial VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    emp_fname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    l_id INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
  INDEX fk_Employee_Location_idx (l_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Employee_Location
    FOREIGN KEY (l_id)
    REFERENCES Customer (loc_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE PiqueExpenses;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer (
    cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cust_fname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_initial VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_lname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    lo_id INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_id),
  INDEX fk_Customer_Location_idx (lo_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Customer_Location
    FOREIGN KEY (lo_id)
    REFERENCES Location (loc_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE PiqueExpenses;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Location (
    loc_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    loc_address VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    loc_city VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    loc_state VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    loc_zip VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    loc_phone_num VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (loc_id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (32.00, 0001, 4, 48.0, .53);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (29.50, 0002, 3.8, 35.0, .44);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (38.75, 0003, 7.6, 49.0, .48);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (42.00, 0004, 8.9, 21.0, .25);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (31.42, 0005, 3.5, 64.0, .58);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (42.25, 0006, 5.6, 82.0, .57);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (38.95, 0007, 6.7, 57.0, .57);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (31.52, 0008, 4.8, 66.0, .61);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (29.60, 0009, 4.4, 52.0, .49);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (pay_rate, j_id, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES (32.50, 0010, 6.4, 70.0, .50);

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0001, 44201, 22001, 'CCTV', 'Install');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0002, 44202, 22002, 'Network','Install');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0003, 44203, 22003, 'Alarm', 'Time&Mater');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0004, 44204, 22004, 'DigitalMenuBoard', 'Install');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0005, 44205, 22005, 'Telecom', 'Troubleshoot');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0006, 44206, 22006, 'DigitalMenuBoard', 'Install');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0007, 44207, 22007, 'Alarm', 'Troubleshoot');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0008, 44208, 22008, 'Telecom', 'Troubleshoot');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0009, 44209, 22009, 'Network', 'Troubleshoot');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, em_id, cus_id, job_name, job_type) 
VALUES (0010, 44210, 22010, 'CCTV', 'Install');

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44201, 'Tom', 'I', 'Butler', 33401);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44202, 'Marty', 'M', 'Tucker', 33402);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44203, 'Tammy', 'T', 'Rivera', 33403);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44204, 'Alicia', 'L', 'Robinson', 33404);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44205, 'Mary', 'J', 'Watson', 33405);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44206, 'Rachel', 'J', 'Owens', 33406);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44207, 'Barb', 'L', 'Wright', 33407);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44208, 'Peter', 'F', 'Parker', 33408);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44209, 'Kathy', 'W', 'Alvarez', 33409);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
emp_lname, l_id) VALUES (44210, 'Frank', 'M', 'Morris', 33410);

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22001, 'Fred', 'F', 'Flinstone', 33411);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22002, 'Buford', 'L', 'Tannen', 33412);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22003, 'Yosimite', 'P', 'Sam', 33413);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22004, 'John', 'A', 'Wayne', 33414);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22005, 'James', 'K', 'Hetfield', 33415);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22006, 'Lars', 'P', 'Ulrich', 33416);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22007, 'Kirk', 'Q', 'Hammet', 33417);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22008, 'Robert', 'F', 'Trajillo', 33418);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22009, 'Alfred', 'P', 'Yankovich', 33419);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, lo_id) VALUES (22010, 'Odell', 'X', 'Beckham', 33420);

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33401, '7613 Bellflower', 
'Mentor', 'OH', '44060', '1-(440)654-7744');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33402, '2346 15th', 'Akron', 
'OH', '44314', '1-(330)848-9413');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33403, '6915 Giddings', 
'Atwater', 'OH', '44201', '1-(330)358-2026');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33404, '11241 Mahoning', 'North 
Jackson', 'OH', '44451', '1-(330)666-9283');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33405, '685 Deercrest', 
'Wadsworth', 'OH', '44281', '1-(330)954-2209');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33406, '675 Wolf Ledges', 
'Akron', 'OH', '44309', '1-(330)996-9756');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33407, '111 Center', 'Medina', 
'OH', '44256', '1-(330)335-1803');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33408, '222 State', 'Cuyahoga 
Falls', 'OH', '44223', '1-(330)388-6354');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33409, '489 Bridge', 'Brimfield', 
'OH', '44240', '1-(330)321-6223');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33410, '44 Chitauqua', 
'Cleveland', 'OH', '44134', '1-(678)980-0852');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33411, '4123 Anniversary Road', 
'Nashville', 'TN', '37215', '1-(615)995-7744');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33412, '9807 Ruskin Crossing', 
'Bellevue', 'WA', '98008', '1-(425)975-9413');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33413, '39 Montana Parkway', 
'Saint Paul', 'MN', '55166', '1-(651)866-2047');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33414, '3 Westridge Street', 
'Stamford', 'CT', '06905', '1-(203)677-2492');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33415, '659 Homewood Junction', 
'Gary', 'IN', '46406', '1-(219)971-2522');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33416, '86460 Kensington Place', 
'Columbus', 'OH', '43240', '1-(614)282-8239');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33417, '4360 Bluestem Pass', 
'Bradenton', 'FL', '34205', '1-(941)335-5180');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33418, '0178 Hallows Pass', 'San 
Antonio', 'TX', '78265', '1-(210)523-6354');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33419, '1816 Trailsway Alley', 
'Sacramento', 'CA', '94245', '1-(916)618-3467');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Location (loc_id, loc_address, loc_city, 
loc_state, loc_zip, loc_phone_num) VALUES (33420, '72464 Armistice Drive', 
'San Jose', 'CA', '95133', '1-(408)405-1270');

COMMIT;

SELECT  * 
FROM    JobPay, 
        Jobs,
        Employee,
        Customer,
        Location;

SELECT  * 
FROM    Employee 
WHERE   emp_initial = 'J';

SELECT  * 
FROM    Jobs 
WHERE   job_type = 'Install';

SELECT *
FROM JobPay
LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs ON JobPay.j_id = Jobs.job_id

UNION

SELECT *
FROM JobPay
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Jobs ON JobPay.j_id = Jobs.job_id;

SELECT *
FROM Customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN Location ON Customer.lo_id = Location.loc_id

UNION

SELECT *
FROM Customer
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Location ON Customer.lo_id = Location.loc_id;
```

Again, unless I'm not seeing something, it seems all tables and inserts are setup similarly but yet Customer seemingly does not exist. Why will it not create the table or exist? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to create a foreign key in `Customer` that references the `Location` table before the `Location` table was created.

The statement `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` gives you some flexibility, like you can load data values for which the referenced parent table doesn't have the same value yet. This allows loading data with circular references.

But it doesn't allow you to reference a table in the FK constraint if that table doesn't exist yet.

It's normal to postpone all definition of FK constraints to the end of your script. Use ALTER TABLE to add FK constraints to tables after all of them have been created.

Answer (score 0):

creating link with something that does not exists yet.  thats location table ...

Comment: That did not fix the error. The same error is being thrown.